# Nuxt3 + Vite + Nitro HMR cache issue

Tags: vite, nuxt3, nitro

I have default project setup getting from `nuxt3` document. I'm talk about this starting point : `npx nuxi init <project-name>`.

The project is up and running on my local machine. Unfortunately output is not up to date in the devtools. For example I made changes on JS part. But I can't see that changes on devtools and it's not impact the result in browser. When I try to clear cache the updated code is working until I do normal refresh on browser. It's so weird and annoying. How do I disable caching. I guess it's still using `app.vue`. But I removed it.

Is anyone else have an idea ?

Edit:
I added `--force` tag to dev script like this;
`"dev": "nuxt dev --force",` It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my solution here if someone need that.
Unfortunately I re-created the project from scratch with same steps. But with one difference. When I do `yarn install`, I didn't run the project. Firstly, I removed the `app.vue` file within the root of the project. Then I created `pages` dir and placed `index.vue` file inside that folder. Now my project is running as I expected.

Note; exactly I copied all the changes from the old project. Just I didn't run the project while `app.vue` exist.

I hope someone find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `vite.config.tz` file in the root directory and added the following in, which seemed to have worked for me. It may not be the best practice, but I'm new to this so not sure

```
export default {
   server: {
      hmr: {
        overlay: false
      }
   }
}
```